# How to make filling from left to right animation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a button with this code

```js
$("body").on('mouseover', '.sign_up_button', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('before_bttn');
});
```

```css
.sign_up_button {
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-out;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Zona;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 120px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #1ed5a3;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.before_bttn:before {
  content: "";
  background: #49d6a7;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: right .3s ease-in;
}

.before_bttn:hover:before {
  right: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sign_up_button">Sign Up</button>
```

What i'm trying to do here is to create animation of background filling from left to right,but unfortunately here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/qantsvg5/ 
Animation happens after mouse leaves the button.How can i create that animation with Jquery? Don't offer ways without css

Comment: background filling from left to right When you hover? or when you click?

Comment: when do you want the animation appear ?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't need another class to be put into the button, so remove the JS code. It works now, hopefully this is what you wanted to happen.

Just rename the `.before_bttn` class to the `.sign_up_button` class.

Hope it helps!

```css
.sign_up_button{
 -webkit-transition:.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:.3s ease-out;
     -ms-transition:.3s ease-out;
      -o-transition:.3s ease-out;
         transition:.3s ease-out;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: Zona;
 color: whitesmoke;
 border:0;
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 120px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background: #1ed5a3;
 cursor:pointer;
 width: 140px;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}
.sign_up_button:before{
 content: "";
 background: #49d6a7;
 top: 0;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
 left: 0;
  transition:right .3s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition:right .3s ease-in;
}
.sign_up_button:hover:before{
 right:0;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sign_up_button">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're better off without jquery, it's easier to just move a div with transition in css:

```js
$('.sign_up_button').one('mouseover',  function(event) {
  $('body').append('you don\'t need jquery');

});
```

```css
.sign_up_button {
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-out;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Zona;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 120px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #1ed5a3;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sign_up_button:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: right .3s ease-in;
}

.sign_up_button:hover:before {
  right: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sign_up_button">
  Sign Up
</button>
```

Comment: Yep, I see our answers are the almost the same :))))